# CURDATE() filter not working on search form

Tags: php, mysql

i have a site that i'm building for a client where users can search for coupons, the search is working but even though i have a date specification in there, and to check if the coupon is active or not, all coupons for a restaurant are showing up ... i can't figure this out. here's my query:

```
include('includes/insert_saved_coup.php');
include('includes/connection.php'); 
global $con;

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

if(isset($_POST['search_sub'])) {

$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['term']);

    $get_rest = "SELECT * 
                FROM menu_restaurants"; 

    $run_rest = mysqli_query($con,$get_rest); 
    $row_rest = mysqli_fetch_array($run_rest);

    $get_results = "SELECT * 
                    FROM menu_coupons
                    WHERE coupon_expire > CURDATE()
                    AND coupon_desc LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_rest LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_title LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_amount LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_tag_one LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_tag_two LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_city LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_state LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    AND coupon_status = 'active'";

    $run_results = mysqli_query($con,$get_results);
    while($row_results = mysqli_fetch_array($run_results)) {
```

the coupon_expire field is a date field and the coupon_status field is a varchar ... i have a cron running everyday in my phpmyadmin to update the status field to show expired ... but when the search is run, it brings up all coupons for that restaurant/city/term even if it is expired or active.

any thoughts? (i have a feeling that it's with my query)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are mixing both `AND` / `OR` conditions and `AND` has higher precedence over `OR`. Try parenthesizing your `WHERE` condition block like below

```
                  SELECT * 
                    FROM menu_coupons
                    WHERE coupon_expire > CURDATE()
                    AND coupon_status = 'active'
                    AND ( coupon_desc LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_rest LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_title LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_amount LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_tag_one LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_tag_two LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_city LIKE '%".$term."%'
                    OR coupon_state LIKE '%".$term."%' );
```

Comment: worked perfectly brother!!! thank you so much @rahul

Comment: @broserdooder, Cool then ... accept the answer.